# Disjoint Sets of Strings - Minimization Problem

Tags: algorithm, set, mathematical-optimization, set-theory

There are two sets, `s1` and `s2`, each containing pairs of letters. A pair is only equivalent to another pair if their letters are in the same order, so they're essentially strings (of length 2). The sets `s1` and `s2` are disjoint, neither set is empty, and each pair of letters only appears once.

Here is an example of what the two sets might look like:

```
s1 = { ax, bx, cy, dy }
s2 = { ay, by, cx, dx }
```

The set of all letters in (`s1` ∪ `s2`) is called `sl`. The set `sr` is a set of letters of your choice, but must be a subset of `sl`. Your goal is to define a mapping `m` from letters in `sl` to letters in `sr`, which, when applied to `s1` and `s2`, will generate the sets `s1'` and `s2'`, which also contain pairs of letters and must also be disjoint.

The most obvious `m` just maps each letter to itself. In this example (shown below), `s1` is equivalent to `s1'`, and `s2` is equivalent to `s2'` (but given any other `m`, that would not be the case).

```
a -> a
b -> b
c -> c
d -> d
x -> x
y -> y
```

The goal is to construct `m` such that `sr` (the set of letters on the right-hand side of the mapping) has the fewest number of letters possible. To accomplish this, you can map multiple letters in `sl` to the same letter in `sr`. Note that depending on `s1` and `s2`, and depending on `m`, you could potentially break the rule that `s1'` and `s2'` must be disjoint. For example, you would obviously break that rule by mapping every letter in `sl` to a single letter in `sr`.

So, given `s1` and `s2`, how can someone construct an `m` that minimizes `sr`, while ensuring that `s1'` and `s2'` are disjoint?

Here is a simplified visualization of the problem:

[image]

Comment: With your current formulation there's no need to treat `s1` and `s2` separately, since the problem doesn't change if you just consider a single set `s = s1 ∪ s2` (i.e., every solution to this new problem is a solution to the original and vice versa). Is that what you intended?

Comment: A key part of the problem is ensuring that `s1'` and `s2'` are disjoint. If we say there's only one input set `s = s1 ∪ s2`, then applying `m` to `s` only generates one output set `s'`. The key part of the problem disappears because we no longer have two output sets to check for disjointedness. So no, I don't think they are the same problem.

Comment: I see now, thanks for explaining!

Comment: There's always a solution in which each character is mapped to a character <= itself. The number of nonisomorphic candidate solutions to check is the number of partitions of a set (Bell number), which is superexponential in the number of characters n. Is an algorithm this slow interesting? I think this problem might be NP-hard, but don't see a reduction yet.

Comment: The solution I'm looking for is the one that minimizes `sr`. So, mapping each character to itself is indeed a solution, but not the ideal solution.

Even though I stated the problem in terms of alphabetical letters (of which there are 26, in English), the real problem I'm working on uses an alphabet of 256 letters. Therefore, there are 256 ^ 256 possible arrangements of `m`. I need an algorithm that will run on a real computer, so a brute-force approach won't work.

Comment: I wrote "to a character **<=** itself", not "to itself". Considering only such solutions reduces the search space without losing optimal-size solutions. The number of partitions of a set is just an upper bound; a branch-and-bound algorithm may still be effective in drastically speeding things up. BTW, what's the application?

Comment: Ah okay, sorry I misread that. The application is in optimizing a parser generator. Essentially, `s1` and `s2` are sets of strings which are UTF-8-encoded Unicode code points (so in the real problem they can be length 1-4, not always length 2, but I figured that's not an important detail). If I can minimize `m`, then I can generate a parser that's much smaller (and therefore faster; fewer cache misses).

Comment: Are s1' and s2' allowed to contain duplicates (due to the mapping)? If not, then you can indeed consider a single set `s = s1 \cup s2` without loss of generality, because disjointness will be equivalent to the requirement that the map m does not create collisions.

Comment: `s1'` and `s2'` are sets, not multisets, so duplicates are ignored. As stated in the problem, "you can map multiple letters in `sl` to the same letter in `sr`"

Comment: If this is for a parser generator, you only really care about single-byte code points. In a preprocessing step, you could map the multi-byte code points to high-value single bytes, and say you don't support more than 100 multibyte code points in the grammar.

Comment: @maniek How is that related to the original problem?

Comment: *Are s1' and s2' allowed to contain duplicates?* : it was asked by @Vincenzo, but I am not sure I understand your answer. In your example, if we map `a` and `b` to `a`, then we get `{ax, ax, ...} = {ax, ...} ` and `{ay, ay, ...} = {ay, ...}`. The obtained sets are still disjoint, but their sizes were decreased. It is allowed?

Comment: This is NP-hard as there is a reduction of graph coloring to your problem, I'll post a short proof of the reduction in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard, to show this, consider reducing graph coloring to this problem.

Proof:
Let G=(V,E) be the graph for which we want to compute the minimal [graph coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring) problem. Formally, we want to compute the chromatic number of the graph, which is the lowest `k` for which G is `k` colourable.

To reduce the graph coloring problem to the problem described here, define

```
 s1 = { zu : (u,v) \in E }
 s2 = { zv : (u,v) \in E }
```

where `z` is a magic value unused other than in constructing `s1` & `s2`.

By construction of the sets above, for any mapping `m` and any edge `(u,v)` we must have `m(u) != m(v)`, otherwise the disjointedness of `s1'` and `s2'` would be violated. Thus, any optimal `sr` is the set of optimal colors (with the exception of `z`) to color the graph G and `m` is the mapping that defines which node is assigned which color. QED.

---

The proof above may give the intuition that researching graph coloring approximations would be a good start, and indeed it probably would, but there is a confounding factor involved. This confounding factor is that for two elements `ab \in s1` and `cd \in s2`, if `m(a) = m(c)` then `m(b) != m(d)`. Logically, this is equivalent to the statement `m(a) != m(c)` or `m(b) != m(d)`. These types of constraints, in isolation, do not map naturally to an analogous graph problem (because of the or statement.)

There are ways to formulate this problem as an (binary) ILP and solve it as such. This would likely give you (slightly) inferior results to a custom designed & tuned branch-and-bound implementation (assuming you want to find the optimal solution) but would work with turn-key solvers.

If you are more interested in approximations (possibly with guaranteed ratios of optimality) I would investigate a SDP relaxation to your problem & appropriate rounding scheme. This level of work would likely be the kind one would invest in a small-to-medium sized research paper.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and thorough answer!